# Where can I ask for tools?

Tags: discussion, support

Where can I ask for tools useful for high school level statistics? Currently I am looking for something that can visualize standard deviation and compare two distributions with each other (with some "levers" so I can easily adjust their shape etc). Googlings just returns a lot of YouTube-clips.

Comment: [Shiny](https://shiny.rstudio.com) is useful for that kind of thing. Anyway, it sounds like that would be on topic at the Software Recommendations S.E. site.

Comment: Many, many people are producing Web apps for elementary statistical procedures.  A few are producing apps to support conceptual learning.  See https://artofstat.com/web-apps for a nice example of the latter.  (It's not the only one--clever searching should be able to find many more hosted at institutions of higher learning to support their beginning stats students.) It's perfectly suited for high school stats.

Answer (score 2):

If you are familiar with a programming language(Matlab, R, Mathematica, Python) or a mathematical software (Excel/SPSS/Maple), googling [what your want] + [programming language] makes searching results more precise.

Answer (score 2):

- https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software
- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/
- https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/
- https://www.reddit.com/r/datascience/
- https://www.reddit.com/r/statistics/